# Yarn link: Importing graphql-js project into another graphql-js project showing another module or realm error

Tags: node.js, graphql, yarnpkg, graphql-js, yarn-workspaces

I am using graphql-js instead of SDL for designing my graphql server. For this, I have created a small library which depends on graphql-js.

Thus, I am linking this library into my main project using yarn (yarn add link:../lib) to build graphql objects and schema.

My package.json files  are given below

graphql-lib/package.json

```
{
"name": "graphql-lib",
"private": true,
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.ts",
"dependencies": {
    "graphql-iso-date": "^3.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/graphql-iso-date": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.5",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
},
"peerDependencies": {
    "graphql": "^15.1.0"
}
}
```

core/package.json

```
{
"name": "@core/schema",
"private": true,
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "graphql-lib": "link:../lib",
    "graphql": "^15.1.0",
    "graphql-iso-date": "^3.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/graphql-iso-date": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0"
}
}
```

graphql-lib testing using ts-jest is working fine.

However, when I am testing my main project I am getting following error -

```
Cannot use GraphQLScalarType "Float" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other 
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.
```

graphql module in the node_modules directory contains only the graphql-js version 15.1.0. I have remove and reinstalled the node_modules in both the packages.

My understanding is that there should single executions instance of graphql. Am I missing something such that graphql instance is created in both the project?  Can I link my project using yarn and maintain a single graphql instance?

Comment: can you run `npm ls graphql` in both project directories and show the results.

Comment: I am using yarn workspace. npm ls showing empty 
> npm ls graphql
@express/app@0.1.0 /mnt/veracrypt1/Project/express/app
└── (empty)
 
with yarn list 
// For graphql-lib 

└─ graphql@15.1.0

// For main 

└─ graphql@15.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error only occurs when there are multiple copies of `graphql-js` in your dependencies. Most commonly it's because there are multiple versions in your `node_modules`. You can verify that's the case by running `npm ls graphql` or `yarn ls graphql` -- if you see multiple versions listed in your dependencies, that's a problem. Typically, this only happens when you have dependencies that directly depend on `graphql-js` (instead of making it a peer dependency). If you use yarn, you can use it's [selective dependency feature](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to get around that issue.

When you're doing local development of multiple packages, you can also run into this issue because you have two different copies of `graphql-js` -- one in each of your two projects. That happens because `npm link` or `yarn add link` only creates a symlink from one of your project's node_modules to the other project. As a workaround, you can link `graphql-js` as well. Go into `node_modules/graphql` inside project A and run `npm link`/`yarn link`. Then go into the root directory for project B and run `npm link graphql`/`yarn link graphql`. Now project B will use project A's copy of the library instead of its own.

Comment: I am using multiple packages for local development.  With the yarn link, I can able to bypass the error.  
-thank you!